# ROS hydro opencv2 linking error during 'catkin_make'

Tags: c++, ros-hydro, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have little problem with my ROS hydro distro. I need to use it for one project so can't change to Indiko.

Problem is that I have used `catkin_create_pkg` packname opencv2 ... for creating my project package. But when I try to invoke `catkin_make` I get following errors:

> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75
> (find_package): Could not find a
> package configuration file provided by
> "opencv2" with any of the following
> names:
>
> opencv2Config.cmake
> opencv2-config.cmake Add the
> installation prefix of "opencv2" to
> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "opencv2_DIR"
> to a directory containing one of the
> above files. If "opencv2" provides a
> separate development package or SDK,
> be sure it has been installed.

I know that opencv2 is installed, because I can find it with `rospack find opencv2` and I can use it in other projects not related to ROS.

I have following lines in CMakeLists.txt and package.xml

CMakeLists.txt:

> find_package(catkin REQUIRED
> COMPONENTS opencv2)
>
> include_directories(
> ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
> > ${opencv2_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
>
> target_link_libraries(BasicObstDetect_node
> ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
> > ${opencv2_LIBRARIES} )

package.xml:

> `<build_depend>opencv2</build_depend>`
>
> `<run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>`

I have tried to use OpenCV instead of opencv2 but that didn't make any difference. Any advices?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194530/ros-hydro-opencv2-linking-error-during-%27catkin_make%27/) by [Greave](https://answers.ros.org/users/20417/greave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OpenCV is a system package in Hydro; not a ROS package.

According to the [vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv?distro=hydro) docs, you should have a **build_depend** and a **run_depend** on opencv2 in your package.xml, and you should add the following to your cmakelists:

```
find_package(OpenCV)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(my_awesome_library ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-08**:
The question refers to *Hydro*.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-10-08**:
Are you sure about that? https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/87e6d5907066d7a753a533c42e9e3bb43497d993/hydro/distribution.yaml#L4615

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-08**:
Yes. opencv2 is distributed as a third-party cmake package.

**Comment by [Greave](https://answers.ros.org/users/20417/greave/) on 2014-10-09**:
Thanks that helped.